# Graph the area of the surface in Spherical Coordinate System

Tags: coordinate-systems

I would like to know how to graph a surface area in spherical given the value of the area. It is because I would to calculate the surface area and I dont know how to visualize which side of the sphere it is. So I can use the correct differential surface area equation.

Here is an example,

Calculate the surface area using differential surface area *dS*.

$r = 10$, $\pi/4 < \theta < 2\pi/3$, $0 < \phi < 2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

You can get Wolfram alpha to generate your graph if you can parametrize your surface as $$x=f(u,v),y=g(u,v),z=h(u,v)$$ using [ParametricPLot$3$D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html).  Using the standard parametrization in your example [WA generates](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D[%7B10*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi]%2C10*Sin[theta]*Sin[phi]%2C10*Cos[theta]%7D%2C+%7BPi%2F4%2Ctheta%2C2Pi%2F3%7D%2C+%7B0%2Cphi%2C2Pi%7D]) the following graph

[image]

Area of this surface is $$\mathrm{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{2\pi/3}10^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi}=100\pi(\sqrt{2}+1)$$